# USB ISO of Linux on ASUS u47a shows "Remove Disks or Other Media" error when booting

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

Recently I downloaded an Ubuntu 16.04 ISO file, copied it onto my USB for booting (making sure the drive format was FAT32), and then stuck it into my ASUS u47a with a WD BLUE SSD and selected it as the boot device.

When booting I get this message:

```
Remove Disks or Other Media:
Press any key to restart.
```

I don't know what to do at this point. My Aptio BIOS doesn't even have a fast-boot option, and even if I set the USB drive to first priority on the list, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *boot* the ISO, simply copying it to a FAT32 partition is not enough. You need to create a bootable USB partition.

If you're currently running Linux or macOS, you can use the `dd` command. See this question for details: [How to copy an ISO image onto USB with dd](https://superuser.com/questions/351814/how-to-copy-an-iso-image-onto-usb-with-dd)

If you're on Windows, you can use [`Rufus`](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). See this page for details: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

**Important Note**: Doing this will delete all files from your USB disk and may make it unusable for storing files until you re-partition it and format it back to FAT32.

Comment: Thx, but I just got a new SSD, do i have to do it on my old HDD first? or can i do it from a working Windows 10 that i do not want to delete?

Comment: @Frank you can do it on any computer